# Cannot get and set value using completion block in Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift

I'm using Xcode 10.1 where I tried to calculate the radius in a completion block by setting the value of another variable called as diameter. The code is given below

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var radius:Double = 10
var diameter: Double{
    get{
        return radius * 2
    }
    set{
        radius = newValue
    }
}
diameter = 30
print(diameter)
```

I'm expecting that the output should be 60.0 but it showing:

> error: Computed property.playground:43:1: error: variables currently 
>   must have an initial value when entered at the top level of the REPL
>   var area: Double{

The output is properly shown in the online compiler of swift but not in Xcode. Now How to get the proper output?

Comment: I execute this code in Xcode10 it's working properly and giving output 60 , that error shows in playground

Comment: I tried several way but i can't fix it. I'm a newbie in swift and don't know how to get the ride from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write this code in a class or struct then create the object of the class or struct then you have to assign diameter value and print it.

```
   /**
    This code you can run in playground
    */
            class Demo {
                var radius:Double = 10
                var diameter: Double {
                    get{
                        return radius * 2
                    }
                    set{
                        radius = newValue
                    }
                }

            }

            let d = Demo()

            d.diameter = 30
            print(d.diameter)

           //Output
           60.0

    /**
    This code you can run in Xcode.
    */
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        var radius:Double = 10
        var diameter: Double {
            get{
                return radius * 2
            }
            set{
                radius = newValue
            }
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            diameter = 30
            print(diameter) // Output: 60.0
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know it can be done by using class or structure but I am looking to solve this specific error related issue.

Comment: This is resolve using class or struct only and if you want to know more about this then you can go with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362893/change-in-xcode-10-playgrounds-variable-initialization-change-are-xcode-10-play